Change Apps Script Google Cloud Platform project number automatically
I am working on an application that leverages Google Sheets and Google Apps Script. The application generates a new Google Sheet along with associated Apps Script code each time the original script is executed.
For OAuth verification, the application must be validated for use across multiple domains. However, an issue arises with the newly created Apps Script projects: they are not automatically linked to my existing Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project. This linkage is essential for the OAuth verification process to function correctly.
Currently, the only way to associate the newly created Apps Script projects with the GCP project is through manual intervention via the Apps Script interface:
Apps Script → Project Settings → Google Cloud Platform → Change Project.
Based on my research, it seems there is no automated way to establish this connection between Apps Script and GCP, which presents a significant challenge since the application frequently generates new files. This manual linking process is time-consuming and inefficient.
Is there a method or workflow to automate the association of newly created Apps Script projects with a predefined GCP project?
Tried using Apps Script API and Google Cloud Resource Manager API but both require direct connection to a GCP Project which is past the current stage I am at.

Programmatically assigning a GAS script to a standard GCP project is not currently possible. Moreover, you are setting yourself up for failure by replicating code across multiple container-bound scripts - that will be a nightmare to maintain. Consider converting your app to either a Google Workspace Add-on or an Editor Add-on (hopefully you app doesn't rely on restricted scopes).
